# Statistical test for multiple measurements per participant where each participant is subject to the influencing variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing

The goal of our study is to test whether migraine patients use their phone differently (e.g., spend less time on their phone) during headache periods compared to non-headache periods. We monitored patients for three months and logged their phone usage. Participants reported their headache periods themselves. Note that every participant in this study suffers from migraine, and has both headache and non-headache periods, which is in contrast to the more typical situation where each participant is in only one group (e.g., a group of migraine patients versus a group of non-migraine patients).

The approach I took to test the difference is the following: for each reported headache period I found corresponding non-headache periods (same start and end hour as the headache, on a day within a period ranging from the week before the headache to a week after the headache; I also make sure that weekend headaches are exclusively paired with weekend non-headache periods, idem for weekdays).
This results in several corresponding non-headache periods for each headache period per person (worth noting that I made sure that no non-headache period appears twice).
Each person has a different number of headache periods (ranging between 2 and 30).
I decided to make one headache - non-headache pair per participant: first by making a single non-headache value for each headache by averaging the values of the corresponding non-headaches, and then by averaging the values of all the headaches and the values of all the non-headaches. This way I have one headache value and one non-headache value per person.
Then I use one-sided Wilcoxon signed-rank test, to test if the difference is symmetric about $\mu < 0$.

Are there any other tests that I can do which would increase the statistical power? I have only 17 subjects. More specifically, I am looking for a test which would allow me to keep the individual pairs per person, instead of having to average them out (as described above).